# C# writing to a .resx file

Tags: c#, addition, resx

I need to write to my resx file, using user submitted values.

Basically the user inputs a value, and the program has to check the resx file to see if the number exists. If the number doesn't exist, it adds it to the file.

Here is the code I have so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if (!DictOfSyndicates.Contains(syndicateNumberTextBox.Text))
{
    try
    {
        var resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\Syndicates.resx");
        resxWriter.AddResource("test", syndicateNumberTextBox.Text);
        resxWriter.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(@"Sydicate "+syndicateNumberTextBox.Text +@" Added Successfully.");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException caught)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Source: " + caught.Source + @" Message: " + caught.Message);
    }   
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(@"Syndicate already exists");
}
```

Anybody have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you get any exception? How should we guess what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't get any exception. When I step through it, it goes into the if try block and it says it adds it, however, DictOfSyndicates does not show it being added. DictOfSyndicates does read the .res file though as its picking up the data that is there already

Comment: Do you check the file in project from Visual Studio or in the Debug folder?

Comment: @shrytyzet The file I want to write to is Sydicates.resx and that is in the Solution Explorer right now, like where all the classes and stuff are. Still haven't gotton this working.

Comment: I don't think the path to the file is ok. In your case there should be a Syndicates.resx in the bin folder. Try with an absolute path.

Comment: @shrutyzet  Yeah the Syndicates.resx exists and it's being read correctly now. One problem now is that when I write a resource to it by getting user input, it keeps replacing the file with the new user input. I want the file to build up so you can have like more than 1 number in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Generate method before calling Close to write out your resources.